Intune - Issues with Nudge - App autoupdate
Recently, we have migrated the devices to Intune (we used WS1 before) and, for some reason, I can't make Nudge available again. I'm deploy the .pkg and the config profile but it's not working at all, I was looking for logs but I couldn't find them. /Library/logs/ and ~/Library/Logs
Previously, we had only Nudge.app but I also deploy Nudge Essentials, Nudge LaunchAgent, Nudge Logger, Nudge Suite. (For testing)
The configuration profile that I'm using I took it from here https://github.com/macadmins/nudge/blob/main/Example%20Assets/com.github.macadmins.Nudge.mobileconfig with some modifications.
<key>requiredInstallationDate</key>
<date>2021-09-30T00:00:00Z</date> (I decided to don't change this to force Nudge to open automatically as the year is 2021)
<key>requiredMinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>14.6.1</string>
<key>targetedOSVersionsRule</key>
<string>11</string>

Any ideas?
Have to say that I have never used Intune before.
Thanks,
J

When you say any ideas are you looking for a different MDM? Do you need a consultant to manage your MDM? Do you need help searching the documents since you’re in IT and responsible for making this work? An edit to show your research  and ask a pointed question might let us offer advice.

I’m not familiar with Intune so I would focus on this part:

I'm deploy the .pkg and the config profile but it's not working at all


Do the entire deployment by hand to ensure you have a good setup for this specific app. Nudge can run by hand so make sure you have a working setup before you try and automate that app configuration.
Keep detailed notes - you don’t have to post all the notes here (in fact dumping too many logs gets you lots of closed questions) but it will help you learn to filter what parts are key to pay attention to over time.
Engage the vendor of your MDM. They should be able to explain exactly where the logs for configuration profile are generated, how to validate them on the MDM side and offer recommendations on what you need for testing profiles. Do they support deploying to VM? Do they require you to have a fleet of physical Macs that you periodically erase and test? Does their tool allow uninstall so you can test a package several times? Do they offer training or certification or a support platform for people to share tips?

